# modifiy dictionary value as out parameter and reference

Tags: c#, entity-component-system

I want to create an Entity-Component-System example. I have components like

```
internal struct Position : IComponent
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
internal struct Movementspeed : IComponent
{
    public float Value { get; set; }
}
```

which implement

```
internal interface IComponent
{
}
```

When looping through the components I want to find them as fast as possible. I thought about creating a Dictionary that takes in the components type as key and the component as value.

```
internal class ComponentCollection
{
    public ComponentCollection()
    {
        components = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    private Dictionary<Type, object> components;

    public void AddComponent<T>(T component) // add a new component
    {
        Type componentType = typeof(T);
        components.Add(componentType, component as IComponent);
    }

    public void RemoveComponent(Type componentType) // remove the component by type
    {
        components.Remove(componentType);
    }

    public bool TryGetComponent<T>(out T component) // get the specified component
    {
        try
        {
            Type componentType = typeof(T);
            component = (T)components[componentType];
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            component = default(T);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

There are two problems that come up.

1. What if someone creates a new MovementspeedComponent using `float movementspeed` and tries to add it? Having two floats would throw an duplicate key exception. I could only add custom struct components which implement the `IComponent` interface to prevent duplicates.
2. When I try to modify the components they are not modified by reference

   ```
   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       ComponentCollection components = new ComponentCollection();
       components.AddComponent(new Position());
       components.AddComponent(new Movementspeed());

       if (components.TryGetComponent(out Position fooPosition))
       {
           fooPosition.X++;
           Console.WriteLine(fooPosition.X); // prints 1
       }

       if (components.TryGetComponent(out Position barPosition))
       {
           Console.WriteLine(barPosition.X); // prints 0
       }

       Console.ReadLine();
   }
   ```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `fooPosition.X++;` is only changing the *copy* of the `Position`. That's how structs work. If you want reference type behavior, it will need to be a class. It's not clear what you're expecting in terms of the first question - but Stack Overflow posts are best done to address *one* issue at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if someone creates a new MovementspeedComponent using float
>   movementspeed

Types are good for keys when we have one object/collection per each type otherwise a `Dictionary<Type, object>` isn't a good fit, key should be unique.

> When I try to modify the components they are not modified by reference

Since all of components are `struct`s this line of code:

```
components.TryGetComponent(out Position fooPosition)
```

Gets *a copy* of struct that we have in the dictionary.
A quote from [C# guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/structs):

> Structs are copied on assignment. When a struct is assigned to a new
>   variable, all the data is copied, and any modification to the new copy
>   does not change the data for the original copy. This is important to
>   remember when working with collections of value types such as
>   Dictionary.
>
> What if someone creates a new MovementspeedComponent using float
>   movementspeed and tries to add it?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions. Either use classes instead of structs or add some Update method to update struct in dictionary

```
public void UpdateComponent<T>(T component)
{
    Type componentType = typeof(T);
    components[componentType] = component;
}
```

Then call this method after you'r done with updating your struct:

```
if (components.TryGetComponent(out Position fooPosition))
{
    fooPosition.X++;
    components.UpdateComponent(fooPosition);
    Console.WriteLine(fooPosition.X); // prints 1
}
```

If you'll use classes instead of structs your old solution should work.

Comment: This is a nice idea. But I don't know if it's worth due to performance?